# Append to existing string variable

Tags: assembly, x86

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/38296c054c65f186c01f82932f78a8aa.png]

In the EDI I got a string, that I want to add ".png" in the end of it.
that string will open as a link, so I just want add that ".png" in the end of it.
I'm pretty noob in ASM, I know I need to do codecave, But I don't really know how to combine those two strings.

EDIT:
The string is dynamic string and it will always be different one, that's why I want to add.

Comment: One possible way is to [hook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) that function that's being called, and then modify the argument and pass it to the original function. But this needs some work.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, but I can't find in google a way to add the string ;D